# Linking error of external library files: C project

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors

I am getting unresolved symbols error in eclipse C project. These symbols are actually from external library files. How can I verify whether those files are part of the entire build process?

Comment: Are you sure you mean C?

Comment: If the linker can't find them, that would indicate that they are not part of the build process!  Way too many details are missing from this question.

Comment: Actually the project is composed of C files. Module/Unit testing part has to be in C++ file.
So test script is CPP file. For that test script to work I needed to use some library files(again cpp).
I am getting unresolved symbols error for those symbols present in the library files

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "external" declarations towards unrecognized symbols to your code, and see if that helps linker. Typically, there should be API *.h file that comes with a library, but not always.